# How to get the style of an element in a JSON format?

Tags: jquery, json, css

I am looking for a function that gives me the `JSON` of all the styles that are applied on the given element in `jquery`

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)  but doesn't seem to work on `Firefox`
Looking for a function that takes an element as an input and returns the `JSON`

Required out put is

```
{
'sidebar' : {
    'background-color' : '#000000',
    'width' : 'auto',

},
'content-area' : {
 'color' : '#000000',
 'width' : '50%',
}
}
```

Comment: The [second solution](/a/6416527/3634538) in the link [should work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#Browser_compatibility), are you sure you have tried `window.getComputedStyle`?

Comment: I am looking for a JSON, this is only copying the style to another element

Comment: So this function should take an array of element as well? What is `sidebar` and `content-area` BTW? Are those the classes or IDs?

Comment: Yes, the function should take an array of the elements. `sidebar` and `content-area` are the classes

Comment: Can you please provide some example input of element in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first line we take all the elements present in the DOM using `document.querySelectorAll("*")` and create an object which will store all the styles. We iterate all the elements using `forEach` loop and only keep the elements who contain some sort of `style`. We store the tag name of the element we are currently on in the loop and make an object with the element name variable inside the original object we just created above. Now with the help of `Object.keys` we get all the key(properties present in style) and then iterate this array with another `forEach` loop. We get all the properties in the style of that element even the unset ones, inside an if statement we only take the keys which have a value and are non numeric so we only get the property names(`color`, `font-size` etc). Inside the object with element tag name we add all the key values of the filtered style. In the end we print the object.

```js
var a=document.querySelectorAll("*")
var obj={};
a.forEach((e)=>{
if($(e).attr('style')!=null)
{
var k=$(e).prop('tagName')
obj[k]={};
Object.keys(e.style).forEach((t)=>{if(e.style[t]!="" && isNaN(t)){
obj[k][t]=e.style[t];
}})}})
console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="div" id="a" style="background-color:green; font-size:20px">aaaa</div>
<span id="b" name="span" style="background-color:blue;font-size:27px">bbb</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jquery-json plugin

eg:

```
var styles = $('#element').attr('style').split(';'),
    json = {style: {}},
    style, k, v;
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/aT77q/

Comment: This helped me! My issue was I was trying to print the contents of style tag to console and wondering why it wasn't printing as a json object. Well, it is ***similar*** to json, but not the same. The solution was to get the innerHMTL instead of the innerText and then split the result on ';' as in your example.